# Can "slit a bag" mean "unzip a bag" or "open a bag"?

Tags: meaning

[britannica.com](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/slit):

> to slit - to make a long, narrow cut or opening in (something) with a sharp object:
> **(1)** *I slit the bag open at the top*.
> **(2)** *The bag of seeds had been slit open*.

According to the definition above, "slit the bag" in (1) and (2) means "cut the bag with a sharp object".
But I want to clarify:
Can "slit" here mean "unzip" or "open" or something other than cutting with a sharp object?

Comment: If it has a zip, it doesn't need to be cut open.

Comment: Why do you think it means something else than the dictionary definition? Have you seen it used with another meaning, and if so where?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. "Slitting a bag" should be used and interpreted literally, meaning a sharp object is used to cut it. If a bag is opened some other way, it should be described as such.